# SQL for Balance Inventory at the end of every month with FIFO concept

Tags: sql

For this data I want to write a procedure which will give balance inventory at the end of every month. In other words we can say that I have to find running balance at end of every month (not group by month) with FIFO concept. Here is the Table

```
create Table transactions ( [Date] Date, SECURITY_NAME VarChar(20), LOC VarChar(20), Investor VarChar(20), BUY_SELL VarChar(10), Quantity numeric(11, 2), TRANS_RATE numeric(11, 2), Inventory_value numeric(11,2) )

Insert into transactions values ('1-Jan-2014', 'HDFC', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 125.00, 125.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('2-Jan-2014', 'ICICI', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 150.00, 145.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('3-Jan-2014', 'Axis', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 25.00, 150.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('4-Feb-2014', 'ICICI', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 100.00, 150.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('5-Feb-2014', 'ICICI', 'HO', 'OS', 'S', 50.00, 185.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('6-Feb-2014', 'HDFC', 'HO', 'OS', 'S', 50.00, 125.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('1-Mar-2014', 'HDFC', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 100.00, 125.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('2-Mar-2014', 'ICICI', 'HO', 'OS', 'S', 125.00, 145.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('3-Mar-2014', 'HDFC', 'HO', 'OS', 'S', 125.00, 150.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('4-Mar-2014', 'ICICI', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 100.00, 175.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('6-Mar-2014', 'Axis', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 125.00, 125.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('5-Apr-2014', 'Axis', 'HO', 'OS', 'S', 75.00, 185.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('6-Apr-2014', 'ICICI', 'HO', 'OS', 'S', 50.00, 125.00, null) 
Insert into transactions values ('6-Apr-2014', 'HDFC', 'HO', 'OS', 'B', 25.00, 125.00, null) 
update transactions set Inventory_value=(quantity*trans_rate)
```

I am trying to get the output like this i.e. at the end of every month quantity balance (with FIFO only)

```
Month   SECURITY_NAME   LOC     Investor    Balance_Qty     Inventry_value 
Jan     HDFC            HO      OS          125             15625 
Jan     ICICI           HO      OS          150             21750 
Jan     Axis            HO      OS          25              3750 
Feb     ICICI           HO      OS          200             29500 
Feb     HDFC            HO      OS          75              9375 
Feb     Axis            HO      OS          25              3750 
Mar     HDFC            HO      OS          50              7500 
Mar     ICICI           HO      OS          175             23750 
Mar     Axis            HO      OS          150             19375 
Apr     Axis            HO      OS          75              9375 
Apr     ICICI           HO      OS          125             21250 
Apr     HDFC            HO      OS          75              10625

Inventory_value=(quantity*trans_rate)
```

Comment: Your post needs some editing and can you provide a sqlfiddle? Can you share the query you have now that doesn't provide the correct output?

Comment: How did u get 200 in Balance_Qty in 4th row? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu at the end of Feb month, 50 is sold from ICICI. So left will be only 150+100-50=200. Now solve this pls

Comment: **150+100-50=200**. From where **100** and **150** came from? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: How did u get 75 after the value 200? Please edit and update the exact calculations in question and make it clear.  I will help you for sure. @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: 150 is from Jan month which was bought  and next 100 is from Feb starting which was bought. So after selling 50, 200 will be left. And same is happening with next 75 i.e. HDFC. Its like running or cumulative calculation at the end of every month. @SarathAvanavu

Comment: For March is the calculation done on new balance of February? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu yes you can do on new balance of Feb also but always take care of left quantity with trans_rate. I am just trying to get the given output. Do however you want. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get *50** in  in Balance_Qty for March? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu at the end of Feb month we had only 75 left of HDFC. In March again bought 100 so total will be 175 and in the same month again sold 125. So total left quantity at the end of Mar will be 50 only. This all will be based on the FIFO concept only.

Comment: Please edit and update the exact calculations in question @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: Take the case of ICICI in March. Balance is 200 in February, bought 125 in March, sold 100 in March. So the balance in March should be (200+125)-100 = 225. But in the expected output its 175. Why is it so? Please make the question clear. Put actual values in both tables. @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Sir you are absolutely correct, but the case you are talking about, it will be (200+100)-125=175. Because there is bought 100 not 125 in March and sold 125 not 100 in March. Please read clearly. All the values are very correct.

Comment: The thing u told is about HDFC. **bought 100 not 125 in March and sold 125 not 100 in March**. I am talking about ICICI. **PLEASE READ CLEARLY** @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Sir same is happening in ICICI case, first it sold 125 from 200 and then bought 100. So total left quantity will be (200-125 (sold)) + 100(bought)=175. Please read it clearly sir.

Comment: How do we know which is bought and which is sold? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu B is for bought and S is for Sold.

Comment: K. Got it. I thought, as you told FIFO it would be like first will be bought and second will be sold. I will update. @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: I am almost done with answer. I just need to know the calculation behind updating **Inventry_value**. How did you get **29500 ** for ICICI in February? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Inventry_value is the multiplication of Balance_Qty and Trans_rate. In case of Feb ICICI we will have 200 as Balance_Qty. This 200 will be with different trans_rates. 100 will be with trans_rate of 145 (because from 150, 50 is sold out) and 100 with trans_rate  of 150. So the inventry_value will be (100*145)+(100*150)=29500. So you also have to take trans_rate  in the query.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Same will happen in all the other cases. So take trans_rate also in the query and then match the result.

Comment: K. Just check Balance_Qty values are correct. I will update that @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. But once you update trans_rate then only I can confirm because the balance quantities will be with different trans_rates depending upon the FIFO (first IN first OUT) calculation. If everything will be correct then it will give the same output what I have written.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu We cannot take first month's data directly. This is just example so here its showing correct but if there will be again and again sold and bought of same or different security names in first month (or in any same month) then this query will be wrong. We have to do calculation (FIFO) at the end of every month.

Comment: So should I take first buy in a month and first sell in a month? @Manish Kumar Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Sir I am not getting what you asking. We just have to remember that the item which will IN (bought) first that will be OUT (sold) first and it will be continued. And this should be followed from the very first transaction (not from the starting of any or every month). It is same as running total or cumulative total month wise or at the end of every month (not group by month) but total or balance quantity at the end of every month should be based on FIFO only.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the logic inside the query

```
CREATE TABLE #NEWTABLE([Month] VARCHAR(20),   SECURITY_NAME VARCHAR(50),   LOC VARCHAR(50),     Investor VARCHAR(50),    Balance_Qty INT,     Inventry_value NUMERIC(18,2))

DECLARE @RNO INT
DECLARE @DATE DATE
DECLARE @SECURITYNAME VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @LOC VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @INVESTOR VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @BUYSELL CHAR
DECLARE @QUANTITY INT
DECLARE @PREV_MONTH_QUANTITY INT
DECLARE @SELL_QUANTITY INT

DECLARE @BAL_QUANTITY INT
DECLARE @RNO_MONTHDATES INT
DECLARE @LASTINMONTH INT

DECLARE @FIRSTMONTH DATE
DECLARE @PREV_MONTH DATE

SELECT @FIRSTMONTH = MIN([DATE]) FROM transactions


DECLARE rollCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT *,
MAX(RNO_MONTHDATES) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]))MAXX 
FROM
(
    select [DATE],SECURITY_NAME,LOC,INVESTOR,BUY_SELL,QUANTITY,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]),SECURITY_NAME ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]), SECURITY_NAME,BUY_SELL) RNO 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]) ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]), (SELECT(0))) RNO_MONTHDATES
    from transactions
)TAB
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]), SECURITY_NAME,BUY_SELL,RNO_MONTHDATES

OPEN rollCursor

-- Loop starts from here 
FETCH NEXT FROM rollCursor
INTO @DATE,@SECURITYNAME,@LOC,@INVESTOR,@BUYSELL,@QUANTITY,@RNO,@RNO_MONTHDATES,@LASTINMONTH

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     -- First month's records will be inserted directly
     IF(DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH,@FIRSTMONTH))
     BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #NEWTABLE
            SELECT @DATE,@SECURITYNAME,@LOC,@INVESTOR,@QUANTITY,NULL
     END

     ELSE IF(DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE) <> DATEPART(MONTH,@FIRSTMONTH))
     BEGIN

        -- If Buy is the 1st record for a SECURITYNAME then it will not take SELL because its  already included inside the below the query
        IF(@RNO = 1)
        BEGIN

            IF(@BUYSELL = 'S')
            BEGIN
                SET @QUANTITY = 0
            END

            SET @PREV_MONTH_QUANTITY=0
            SET @SELL_QUANTITY=0

            -- Finds previous month quantity
            SELECT  @PREV_MONTH_QUANTITY = ISNULL(Balance_Qty,0)
            FROM #NEWTABLE 
            WHERE SECURITY_NAME = @SECURITYNAME
            AND DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) = 
            (SELECT MAX(DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH])) FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) < DATEPART(MONTH,CAST(@DATE AS DATE)))

            -- Find current month's Sell Quantity of current SECURITYNAME 
            SELECT @SELL_QUANTITY  = ISNULL(Quantity,0) FROM transactions 
            WHERE SECURITY_NAME = @SECURITYNAME AND BUY_SELL = 'S' AND DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE) = DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE])

            INSERT INTO #NEWTABLE
            SELECT @DATE,@SECURITYNAME,@LOC,@INVESTOR,(@PREV_MONTH_QUANTITY+@QUANTITY)-@SELL_QUANTITY,NULL

        END     

        -- If it is last record in current month, it finds out the missing SECURITYNAME in current month, take from previous month and add as current month
        IF(@RNO_MONTHDATES = @LASTINMONTH)
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #NEWTABLE
            SELECT CAST(CAST(YEAR([MONTH]) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(@DATE) AS VARCHAR(14))+'-01' AS DATE),
            SECURITY_NAME,LOC,INVESTOR,BALANCE_QTY,INVENTRY_VALUE 
            FROM #NEWTABLE
            WHERE SECURITY_NAME IN
            (
                SELECT SECURITY_NAME 
                FROM #NEWTABLE 
                WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) = 
                (SELECT MAX(DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH])) FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) < DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE))         
                EXCEPT
                SELECT SECURITY_NAME 
                FROM #NEWTABLE 
                WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) = DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE)
            )
            AND DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) = 
            (SELECT MAX(DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH])) FROM #NEWTABLE WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[MONTH]) < DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE))         

        END

     END

    FETCH NEXT FROM rollCursor
    INTO @DATE,@SECURITYNAME,@LOC,@INVESTOR,@BUYSELL,@QUANTITY,@RNO,@RNO_MONTHDATES,@LASTINMONTH
END 

CLOSE rollCursor;
DEALLOCATE rollCursor;


SELECT CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,[Month])AS VARCHAR(3)), SECURITY_NAME,LOC,Investor,Balance_Qty,Inventry_value  
FROM #NEWTABLE
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46ebb3/4) to view the result

Please add the calculation to find the `Inventry_value` for the new table.